# Javascript: Mysql date and time duration

Tags: javascript, mysql, momentjs

I have a little problem when filtering a record, what I want is the query will return true if the date is not in the record, the query result will only be false if the `newDate(form)` is in between the `startDate(field)` and the `duration(field)`

```
var newDate = "15/04/2022 10:07 AM"

var duration = 3600000
```

This is my current query

```
sql = "SELECT startDate FROM Event WHERE startDate BETWEEN '" + moment(newDate).startOf(`day`) + "' AND '" + moment(newDate).endOf(`day`) + "'
if(sql.length > 0){
  valid = true
}else{
   valid = false
}
```

record inside the database

I've tried this

```
"SELECT id, startDate, FROM_UNIXTIME(duration / 1000) FROM Event WHERE '" + date + "' BETWEEN startDate AND FROM_UNIXTIME(duration / 1000)"
```

i've got always nothing

[image]

Comment: *This is my current query* This is not a query, this is javascript (or jscript?) code. And what is the reason to check the SQL code length?

Comment: *I've tried this* When you need to add duration value in ms to datatime value you must use `datetime + INTERVAL duration MILLISECOND` expression.

Comment: it is javascript code, the `FROM_UNIXTIME` is wrong because the year is `1970`

Comment: I just want to convert the field duration as datetime

Comment: But i dont know how to do it

Comment: *I just want to convert the field duration as datetime* This is absolutely impossible. INTERVAL and DATETIME are 2 different datatypes which cannot be converted to each other correctly. For to solve (if I understand the task correctly) you must check that needed date value is [not] between datetime and datetime+interval. See according expression above.